# Consulta SQL - Dúvida Condicao Datas

Tags: sql, sql-server, query, sql-server-2012

Galera, boa tarde! Estou com dificuldade na consulta abaixo. Estou querendo que traga todas as tarefas apenas quando o vencimento (campo tarvencimento) delas forem iguais ao mês posterior da data de abertura (tardata). Porém, não veio nada na consulta.

```
select * 
from Tarefa 
where TarID = 173151 
    and MONTH(TarVencimento) = DATEADD(MONTH,1,TarData)
```

Comment: Tá estranha essa consulta, explique melhor TarID exemplo TarID = 173151 com vários vencimentos?

Comment: resolveu renan ?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis, resolveu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que seja mais ou menos isso que precisa, segue meu teste:

```
CREATE TABLE teste(tarId INT, TarVencimento DATE);

INSERT INTO teste VALUES(173151,'2017-12-01'),(173151,'2018-01-01'),(173151,'2018-02-01');

SELECT
    *
FROM
teste a
INNER JOIN
(
select
    tarId,
    TarVencimento 
from teste
where tarId = 173151
) as aux
ON a.tarId = aux.tarId
WHERE month(aux.TarVencimento) = month(a.TarVencimento + interval 1 month)
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A fatura 1 tem como referencia a 2(Mês posterior) e a fatura 2 tem a 3(Mês posterior dela)

Se quiser pegar apenas 1 pode ordenar por TarVencimento ASC e adicionar um LIMIT 1

Answer (score 3):

Só contextualizando a reposta do @Rovann

O [DATEADD](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql) retorna uma data. O [MONTH](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/month-transact-sql) retorna um inteiro que representa o mês da data.

Logo sua clausulá where `MONTH(TarVencimento) = DATEADD(MONTH,1,TarData)` não parece fazer sentido.

Passa a fazer mais sentido sua clausulá `where`, alterando ela para `MONTH(TarVencimento) = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,1,TarData))`. Onde você adiciona 1 mês ao campo `TarData`, pega o mês e por último compara com o mês da `TarVencimento`.

Vendo sua pergunta, vejo que parei no tempo com os estudos do *SQL Server*, pois eu ainda uso o [DATEPART](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql) para pegar o mês nos campos datas, ficando algo do tipo: `DATEPART(MONTH, TarVencimento) = DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH,1,TarData))`, o que não deixa de estar certo também, pois o [DATEPART](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql) retorna um inteiro que representa a *datepart* da data especificada.

Answer (score 2):

Se eu entendi direito: ?!

```
select * 
from Tarefa 
where TarID = 173151 
    and MONTH(TarVencimento) = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,1,TarData))
```